# How to format the List output in specific format in Powershell?

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to create a list of Id's in specific format as shown below:

RequiredFormat:

```
{id1},{id2}
```

My code:

```
[System.Collections.Generic.List[System.String]]$IDList = @()
        foreach ($key in $keys) {
             $id =  $sampleHashTable[$key]
             $IDList.Add($id)   
        }
        echo  $IDList
```

My output:

```
id1

id2
```

How to convert my output into required format?

Comment: the possible way to have your desired output `{id1},{id2}` is as a `String`. Will no longer be a List or Array. Are you aware / ok with that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To complement [Mathias' helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75098620/45375) with a [PowerShell (Core) 7+](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md) alternative, using the [`Join-String`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/join-string) cmdlet:

```
# Sample input values
[System.Collections.Generic.List[System.String]] $IDList = 'id1', 'id2'

# -> '{id1},{id2}'
$IDList | Join-String -FormatString '{{{0}}}' -Separator ','
```

- `-FormatString` accepts a format string as accepted by the .NET [`String.Format`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.String.Format) method, as also used by PowerShell's [`-f`operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#format-operator--f), with placeholder `{0}` representing each input string; *literal* `{` characters must be *escaped* by doubling, which is why the enclosing `{` and `}` are represented as `{{` and `}}`.

---

Alternatives that work in *Windows PowerShell* too:

[Santiago Squarzon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15339544/santiago-squarzon) proposes this:

```
'{{{0}}}' -f ($IDList -join '},{')
```

Another - perhaps somewhat obscure - option is to use the regex-based [`-replace`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Comparison_Operators#replacement-operator) operator:

```
$IDList -replace '^', '{' -replace '$', '}' -join ','
```

Answer (score 2):

You can surround each list item in `{}` and then join them all together like this:

```
$IDList.ForEach({"{${_}}"}) -join ','
```

If you want to avoid empty strings in the list, remember to test whether the key actually exists in the hashtable before adding to the list:

```
foreach ($key in $keys) {
    if ($sampleHashTable.ContainsKey[$key]){
        $id = $sampleHashTable[$key]
        $IDList.Add($id)
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Mathias .. Can you please look into this query ?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75105771/how-to-convert-string-to-object-in-powershell