# How to convert String to Object[] in powershell?

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to convert String datatype to Object[].

Required Format and Required Datatype:

```
$demilimitedIds = {/subscriptions/XXX},{/subscriptions/XXX}
echo  $demilimitedIds.GetType().Name  ##datatype of $demilimitedIds is Object[]
```

My Code:

```
[System.Collections.Generic.List[System.String]]$IDList = @()
        $IDList.Add("/subscriptions/XXX")   
        $IDList.Add("/subscriptions/XXX")

        $Alist =  '{{{0}}}' -f ($IDList -join '},{') 
        echo "%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%"
        echo  $Alist.GetType().Name //o/p format of $Alist is String
        echo "%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%"
```

I'm trying to convert the $IDList into required format similar to  $demilimitedIds and of same Object[] datatype.

How to convert datatype of $Alist from String to Object[] ?

Comment: What do you actually need? To convert `$Alist` to an object or just create an object from values instead of the way you're creating `$IDlist`?

Comment: $Alist is to create an object from values instead of the way you're creating $IDlist and this datatype should be Object[] to send as a parameter to other powershell command

Comment: `$IDList` can already be used as Object[] with a parameter.  If you really need to use `$Alist` then `$Alist = @($IDList)` will give you Object[] with the contents of `$IDList`

Comment: Hi Daniel .. First I need convert the $IDList into this format {/subscriptions/XXX},{/subscriptions/XXX}.After conversion stored in $Alist. This $Alist datatype is coming as String. Need to convert this String datatype to Object[]

Comment: `$Alist = @($Alist)`

Comment: If you need it as an object, why are you creating `$Alist` as a string?

Answer (score 0):

Still not clear what you're trying to achieve here, but...

```
# Just create $IDlist as an object:

$IDList = New-Object PSObject           
$IDList.Add("/subscriptions/XXX")   
$IDList.Add("/subscriptions/XXX")
```

Having said this, you can use $IDlist as an input object already as Daniel mentions

Comment: $IDList is to be formatted first and should be stored in $Alist and this $Alist should be of Object[] to send as parameter to other powershell command

Answer (score 0):

Or use a ForEach-Object loop like

```
$IDList = [System.Collections.Generic.List[System.String]]::new()
$IDList.Add("/subscriptions/XXX")   
$IDList.Add("/subscriptions/XYZ")

$Alist = $IDList | ForEach-Object {'{{{0}}}' -f $_ }
```

$Alist is now a string array (`Object[]`) containing

```
{/subscriptions/XXX}
{/subscriptions/XYZ}
```